# How can I poll for results from a job and terminate when status is done using rxjs6?

Tags: rxjs, polling, rxjs6

Imagine a service that has three endpoints.

1. Submit a job and get back a job ID
2. Submit a status request and get back a status
3. Submit a results request and get back results

I need a solution to submit the job and poll for results until the status of the job is done. Because the status and results endpoints are independent, I need to make sure I make one last results request after it is determined that the status is DONE.

I have tried using many rxjs operators to no avail. I can get the polling easy but the hard part is stoping the polling at the exact right time. When I use takeWhile or takeUntil, my polling stops before I can get the results.

```
return submitJob(request).pipe(
  delay(500), // Delay start of poll
  switchMap(job => getResults(job).pipe(
    repeatWhen(c => c.pipe(delay(1000))), // Keep getting results every second
    takeUntil(getStatus(job).pipe(
      filter(status => status.done)
    ))
  )
);
```

The problem is, the status of the Job is done immediately and the results call is canceled. My code never actually submits a results request. I need to make at least one call to get results AFTER the status comes back as done.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [timer operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer) for scheduling requests, and then stop when the first 'done' status was received, see the example:

```js
const { of, interval, timer } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { tap, take, filter, mergeMap } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

// simulate API methods
const submitJob = id => of('newjob');
let tries = 0;
function getStatus() {
  tries += 1;
  if (tries === 5) return of('done');
  return of('working...');
}
const getResult = () => of('result');

const job$ = submitJob().pipe(
  tap(e => console.log('started job: ', e)),
  // wait 500ms and then make request every 1000ms
  mergeMap(e => timer(500, 1000).pipe(
    // request status every 1 second
    mergeMap(t => getStatus()),
    tap(e => console.log('status: ', e)),
    // when 1 'done' received - stop polling
    filter(status => status === 'done'),
    take(1)
  )),
  mergeMap(e => getResult())
)

job$.subscribe(e => console.log('completed: ', e));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.3.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```